# Highcharts: make y-axis extremes the same for two data series with different units

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart where two graphs/series have different units. Therefore the y-Axis is different and the extremes are calculated separately from each other.

Is there a way to tell Highcharts to **use the same scale**, despite the different units, across all graphs/series?

Below is the chart. Relevant y-axis are the ones on the right, as an example. The units are different: "W/m^2" and "kW/kWp", however I want the scale to be the same.

[image]

Of course, one way would be a manual approach: in my controller, to go through all the data series and check the overall minimum and maximum value of all data series and then apply the extremes manually via

```
chart.yAxis[i].setExtremes(min, max)
```

but I was wondering if Highcharts has any way, like a configuration option, to achieve this.
I didn't find anything in the docs so far.

Thanks.

Comment: (since you have an answer already) If they're going to be the same scale, why bother having two axes in the first place? Seems like a lot of extra space to use for redundant information.

Comment: Because the unit labels are different. "W/m2" vs "kW/kWp". This cannot be solved with one axis.

Comment: A legend? A label at the end of each line? Obviously do what works for you, but the statement that it can't be solved with one axis doesn't make sense. You're taking up the space of an entire extra axis, for no purpose other than making a spot for a label. You can just apply a label, without building a second entirely redundant axis.

Comment: I don't see how that would work. I don't mean one label, I mean two labels (see the alignment and position of "W/m2" and "kW/kWp"). Just like in my screenshot. But also in my app, the user has a button to toggle the linking of all axes together or not, so I need to keep it separated. Right, I use some extra space for the axis, but it doesn't matter, the screen is big enough. A legend is suboptimal, because a legend would not show the info right at the scale. Also, my app allow to show/hide each graph independently from the chart, therefore I need the axes separated as well.

Comment: 1) in Highcharts you can place any number of labels anywhere you want 2) you could use a legend, since what you're identifying is really what the series is 3) you could add a data label to the last point of each series identifying the appropriate units, etc., etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. First time I'm using Highcharts. I will consider this eventually, whether it would make more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to achieve that. You can link one axis to another via linkedTo property.

From API:

> **linkedTo : Number**
>
> Index of another axis that this axis is linked to. When an axis is linked to a master axis, it will take the same extremes as the master, but as assigned by min or max or by setExtremes. It can be used to show additional info, or to ease reading the chart by duplicating the scales.
>
> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n8tokqru/

```
    yAxis: [{

    }, {
        linkedTo: 0
    }],
```

Comment: It works fine when the extremes of yAxis 0 has the lowest and highest extremes. Then all data is shown in the graph. Just need to figure out now which axis to link to. Since I want to have all graphs in the visible area, I need to check the min/max extremes of all axes first, then choose the one with the lowest/highest extremes. (For example, if I switch the data array in your jsfiddle, not both graphs are in the visible area anymore.) Nevertheless, your hint to this linkedTo method is very helpful already.

Comment: In this case, you would need to find min and max values as you mentioned in the question, e.g. like this http://jsfiddle.net/n8tokqru/1/ - doing this on load changes the animation, but this can be done before the chart is initialized as well.